# What is the meaning of "house" in the following context which may be a game?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> To play the game, one of the players—either the user or the
>   program—has to go first. Alternatively, we can use a probability to make the choice. For example, we can give the same choice for two players, i.e., 50/50 odds by default. Or, we can give the program a better choice of going first, i.e., giving the **house** a slight edge.

So in the above context, what is the meaning of *house*? I can't understand the usage of *house* here.

Sorry for my poor English to adapt the original for the above context.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a play on the gambling tenet, "the house always wins," the house meaning the casino/betting parlor.  In this case, the "house" is the computer AI player.

Comment: Not really a play on the term, just using it in the same sense.

Comment: @RupertMorrish You're probably right.  I guess I just though that because they chose to use the word "house" when they could have just said "the program."

Answer (score 2):

This is definition #13 at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/house) (you may need to expand the list of definitions to find it):

> the management of a commercial establishment or of a gambling casino

Gambling games often have different rules for the house (in the person of the dealer or croupier) than for other players.

Comment: Thanks. I have referred to a dictionary, but the dictionary has no such meaning.

Comment: @RupertMorrish The link must be wrong. No mention of gambling or casinos.

Comment: You have to click the arrow under definition number 7.
I'll try and find a usable link.

Comment: @RupertMorrish Erm - 'gambling games have different rules for house and players' ? Isn't that illegal ?

Comment: @RupertMorrish Yep. Got the link.

Comment: No, it's "house rules". I'm thinking of rules like "the house has to stick on 16 or higher" in Blackjack, for example, or the house wins on 0 in roulette.

Comment: @NigelJ Another example: In blackjack, the dealer gets to keep his hole card face down but the players have to keep all their cards face up, making it harder to predict their odds of winning.